# What is the reward?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> You come in a room, there is someone on a stage, saying something. He
> has a star and a number that changes on his chest.
>
> There is a lot of people in this room, only the ones who speak also
> have a number that can change on their chest.
>
> Then you speak, the person on the stage comes to you and gives you a
> reward, that he places on your chest, at the same place where he has
> his star.
>
> Your’re really proud of this reward, and after a while, when you leave
> this room, you realise that you no longer have your reward.
>
> You’re afraid and go back to the room to see if you’ve lost it somewhere
> inside it, and when you come back in, you’re relieved, because you see
> that your reward is still on your chest.

**What reward did this person give you?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the reward is a

> Green Tick

Explanation

> The room is the page of a question on stack exchange and the person on stage is the question asker. The number and the star are the number of votes (which can change) and the star representing the number of times the question has been favourited, respectively. When you speak, it is to answer the question and, if given the green tick, it appears underneath the vote number, the same place where the star is on the question. You don't see the green tick when you leave the page of the question but you can always come back to see it.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, good job ;)

Comment: @RémiHenry Thank you, it is a good question.